# Filling list with empty vectors causes its length to change

Tags: r, vector

In the following code, I was expecting something of length 96, but I get a list of length 48. Can you explain this result?

```
num_empty = 96
empty_vecs = as.list(1:num_empty)
for(i in 1:num_empty){empty_vecs[[i]] = c()}
length(empty_vecs)

[1] 48
```

Now I'll answer the question that led me to encounter this behavior. The original question was, "How do I make a list of empty vectors in R?" and the answer was "Replace `c()` with `character()` in the above code."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting list elements equal to `c()` (aka `NULL`) removes them, and this loop therefore has the effect of deleting every other element in your list. To see this, consider a smaller example, iteratively printing out the resulting vector:

```
e <- list(1, 2, 3, 4)
e
# [[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4
# 
e[[1]] <- c()
e
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 4
# 
e[[2]] <- c()
e
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4

e[[3]] <- c()
e
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4

e[[4]] <- c()
e
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 4
```

Note that if you actually wanted to create a list of 96 NULL values, you might try:

```
replicate(96, c(), FALSE)
```

Comment: Another way is: `rep(list(NULL), 96)`

Comment: Asa side note , if you do it in the reverse order  `for(i in num_empty:1){empty_vecs[[i]] = c()}` the list will be empty.

Comment: I might make it more clear that `c()` is a function that returns `NULL` when passed no parameters in the output. `c()` is not the "vector" function that everyone seems to think it is. It's for concatenating vectors. `c()` doesn't create an empty vector in the same way `character()` or `numeric()` does.

Comment: And as for why this deletes - From `?"[["` : "Note that in all three kinds of replacement, a value of ‘NULL’ deletes the corresponding item of the list."